# Access WPF user Control properties

Tags: wpf, treeview, controls

I've included a WPF control in my Winform C# application, now I would like to access some of the properties of the control. It is a Treeview and I'd like to get this:
Here's the code in XAML:

```
<TreeView Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Margin="5,5,5,5" Name="mytreeview" 
          BorderThickness="0" FontSize="12" FontFamily="Courier New"/>
```

And what I'm trying to acomplish:

```
//host3d is the integration object

  host3d.Controls["mytreeview"].Items.Add("test");
```

I'm getting an error, saying controls doesn't contain that definition "Items" which makes sense, I'm sure there's a way to access the methods of the treeview...

Comment: Try this - `host3d.mytreeview.Items.Add("test");`

Comment: I get this:
Error 1 'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost' does not contain a definition for 'mytreeview' and no extension method 'mytreeview' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.Integration.ElementHost' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Instead of `Name`, have you tried setting `x:Name` on your Treeview like this `x:Name="mytreeview"`.

Comment: yes, and didn't work..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a WPF user control and using ElementHost control to host my wpf control in winform application. Then I can use any property from my user control as below

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    UserControl1 control = new UserControl1();
    elementHost1.Child = control;

}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UserControl1 control = elementHost1.Child as UserControl1;
    String names = string.Empty; ;
    foreach (var item in control.Patients1)
    {
        names += item.Name + "\n";
    }
    MessageBox.Show("Name: \n" + names);
}
```

If you are using WPF you can bind your treeView to a collection and access the collection items from anywhere. I have binding to Patients list and I have direct access to it.